# Convert strings with many numbers then add all

Tags: javascript, parsing

So far this code for me is working:

```
 var x;
 var y;
 var z;

function functionWithArgs(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x + y + parseInt(z)); // I get a sum of 6
}

functionWithArgs(1, 2, "3b");
```

But when I do this:

```
  var x;
  var y;
  var z;

function functionWithArgs(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x + y + parseInt(z)); //
}

functionWithArgs(1, 2, "987b8h76");
```

I get an error message. Any suggestions please. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: What error message do you get? And why do you have those `var` statements? You don't need to declare the parameter variables of a function.

Comment: What number are you expecting to get from `987b8h76`?

Comment: I don't get an error message. What error message do you get?

Comment: I get a result of `990` when I try your second example.

Comment: @Barmar What is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: Hi , I am trying to remove all strings or letters from "987b8h76", I thought if I use parseInt it will convert all to numbers.

Comment: Sorry, it did work now, I thought I was doing it wrong. How to close this topic?

Comment: `parseInt()` will parse the integer at the beginning of the string, it won't use all the numbers.

Comment: @IsabelHM That's the result I expect. A better question would be what the OP expected.

Comment: What you need in addition to parseInt is a Regex to remove all non-numeric character.

Comment: @anthonycrisart Click on `flag` and request that the moderators close it.

Comment: I see, yes when it converted to 990 I realized the other numbers were left out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function functionWithArgs(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x + y + parseInt(z.replace(/\D+/g, ''), 10));
}

functionWithArgs(1, 2, "987b8h76");  // 987879
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function functionWithArgs(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x + y + parseInt(z.replace(/\D/g,''))); //
}

functionWithArgs(1, 2, "987b8h76");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

```javascript
var x;
var y;
var z;

function getNum (s) { return s.replace(/[^0-9]/ig,""); }

function functionWithArgs(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x + y + parseInt(getNum(z))); //
}

functionWithArgs(1, 2, "987b8h76");
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript parseInt("som3symb0ls") will cause an error on interpreting the script since javascript likes single quotes.

change this:

```
functionWithArgs(1, 2, "987b8h76")
```

to:

```
functionWithArgs(1, 2, '987b8h76')
```

if you run this with your code it will return 990

For javascript your might want to add:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp
to your bookmarks 
Super site for JS, HTML, DOM stuff